# Mobile Edge: css line-height: 3em with two lines of text expands vertically

Tags: css

Have a table with 3m height and cells 1st child 1em 2nd child 3em

```
    .idx td {height: 3em}
    .idx td:nth-child(1) {line-height: 1em; font-weight: 200}
    .idx td:nth-child(2) {line-height: 3em; font-weight: 200}
```

First TD displays Locality but if Suburb name available I display:

Suburb 
 Locality

Since line-height in first child is 1em both lines should use the same height of 3m in TD

In chrome it display well, in google F12 developer mobile test ok, but with **Edge mobile** the second line separates like 3em instead of respecting the 1em, already tried setting style to 1em for both lines of text but still Edge separate lines by a big space.

IS there any webkit of edge hack to prevent Edge respect line-height and TD height ?